# how to sum up particular record in table based on two parameters in ms access using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

i have table named as productstock. In that table i have described the columns like below structure

```
Particulars     Name     Qty  
30              Red       30  
40              Green     40  
50              Yellow    10  
30              Red       20  
50              Yellow    40  
60              Pink      20
```

i want to query the result from the above table like below structure.

```
Particulars     Name     Qty  
30              Red       50  
40              Green     40  
50              Yellow    50  
60              Pink      20
```

how do i get achieved this query in ms access query using vb.net? is this possible?

Comment: Google: SQL GROUP BY and SUM

Comment: Group By Name Order By Particulars Desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select productstock.Particulars, productstock.Name, SUM(productstock.Qty) 
From productstock 
Group By productstock.Particulars, productstock.Name 
Order By productstock.Particulars
```

Comment: superb sir its working! can you help me, how to use this in sub query?